# Cast an object to a type of float but it looks like struct System.Single

Tags: c#, uwp

My code looks like this and `float` is the datatype of [Control.CornerRadius](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.control.cornerradius):

```
Application.Current.Resources.TryGetValue("RoundButtonSize", out object size);
control.CornerRadius = ((float)size) / 2;
```

However when I do the cast on the second line it says invalid cast and when I checked here I find that it's not casting to a float as I expect:

```
var a = (float)size ;
```

It says that the datatype of a is `Struct System.Single`

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong with the cast?

Comment: Does that even compile? I count 3 open brackets and 2 close brackets

Comment: `System.Single` is same as `float`.

Comment: @CaiusJard the brackets match

Comment: Hah, on an iPad, the right hand side of the first line is cut off without a visible scroll bar

Comment: Docs say corner radius is a specific type https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.cornerradius?view=netframework-4.7.2 - is it the right doc?

Comment: @CaiusJard has the answer. Also: float is a built-in name for System.Single. When you ask the runtime (or maybe the debugger) for the type name you get System.Single. The string "float" does not make it into the compiled binary at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[CornerRadius](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.cornerradius?view=netframework-4.7.2) accepts a parameter of [Double](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double?view=netframework-4.7.2). A [Single Struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.single?view=netframework-4.7.2) is a float.

```
control.CornerRadius = ((float)size) / 2;
```

Should read:

```
control.CornerRadius = new CornerRadius((double)size/2);
```

I would assume that this

```
It says that the datatype of a is Struct System.Single
```

applies to the CornerRadius not var a.

I have no idea what you're doing with

```
var a = (float)size ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is the object type you’re dealing with:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.cornerradius?view=netframework-4.7.2

Cast to this type and then access the relevant corner property you want- there are four of them. When you make a new corner radius instance using the constructor that takes one Double, it sets all four corners to the same value but they can be different

```
var a = ((CornerRadius)size).TopLeft;
```

You hence cannot cast it to a float, because it’s more complex than that, kinda like specifying `Animal a = new Animal(4)` for a four legged animal, then being surprised that you can’t cast the animal to an int and retrieve `4`

When you complained that the second line was invalid cast, that’s because you can’t assign a float to a property of type CornerRadius. The docs state it should be used like this:

```
control.CornerRadius = new CornerRadius(15);
```

@usr makes a good point; your third line of code:

```
var a = (float)size ;
```

..is a red herring, leading you away from the original problem and into focusing on “why when I cast something to a float does the debugger tell me it’s a single?” - separate question, and one of synonyms. If you cast something to `long` the debugger would tell you it’s an `Int64`, `bool` is synonymous with `Boolean`, `float` with `Single` etc. What you call a float/Single and what the runtime calls it doesn't have any bearing on the fact that you can't assign a primitive numerical type to a CornerRadius - you have to assign an object instance of type CornerRadius